# How to edit button color?

Tags: color, gimp, png

I have this button in PNG format and I want to change it to blue using Gimp or some other free tool (and keep the transparency).

[image]

Comment: What's the file format, png, vector? have you tried searching on google or this site for your answer?

Comment: it looks really simple. Why don't you create it from scratch with the necessary color

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can properly open your image in GIMP and save, too:

In GIMP there's the Hue & Saturation tool. Cross the red shades to be changed and move the HUE slider. It's the same in Photoshop.

To keep the effect off from other red objects, make at first a selection by lasso or some other selection tool.

NOTE: GIMP cannot save vector formats, only raster.